# Subsection in admin menu

Tags: magento2, adminmenu

Hey I'm trying to add a menu item in the Magento 2 backoffice but I want to create sections like this (Elements & Design):

[image]

Here is my Arno/Blog/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml:

```
<menu>
    <add id="Arno_Blog::main" title="Arno Blog" sortOrder="100" module="Arno_Blog" resource="Arno_Blog::main"/>

    <add id="Arno_Blog::main_blog" title="Blog"  module="Arno_Blog" resource="Arno_Blog::main_blog" parent="Arno_Blog::main"/>

    <add id="Arno_Blog::posts" title="Manage Blog posts"  module="Arno_Blog" resource="Arno_Blog::posts"
         parent="Arno_Blog::main_blog" action="arno_blog/blog"/>

</menu>
```

I think I'm doing it right but I still don't get the 'Blog' section.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a fault in your code but a feature (or bug) in Magento 2.2.x, that it does not show parent menu title if it has only one submenu.

Please check:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13707

and

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/d91e96b529e70dcec55d3b5336b471791dc42d54

Please try to add multiple menu items (having at least one submenu item) and then check.

Comment: This is indeed the problem I added my items to the "content" main menu item and this works. Thanks